# limiting the length of the text entered from the virtual keyboard

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I have following code that use softkey keyboard plugin. I have a problem with max lenght of text when i'm using virtual keyboard. When i'm typing on normal keyboard max lenght of text is 10 characters but when i'm start use virtual keyboard i can type how many characters i want. How can i type text lenght to max 10 characters from virtual keyboard. Please help.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="softkeys-0.0.1.css">

    <style>
       body { background-color:#fafafa; font-family:'Roboto';}
       #v{width:600px; hight:400px; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div  style="border:2px inset #AAA ;height:50px; width:500px;font-
family:Lobster;font-size:30px" 
      id="d" ></div>
<script>
$('.softkeys').click(function() {
$('#d').text($(this).val());
});
</script>
<div id="v">
 <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="a" name="code" class="form-control 
input-lg"style="height:50px; width:500px; font-family: 'Lobster', 
cursive;
    font-size:10px"></form>
 <div class="softkeys" data-target="input[name='code']"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="softkeys-0.0.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.softkeys').softkeys({
                target : $('.softkeys').data('target'),
                layout : [
                    [
                        ['`','~'],
                        ['1','!'],
                        ['2','@'],
                        ['3','#'],
                        ['4','$'],
                        ['5','%'],
                        ['6','^'],
                        ['7','&amp;'],
                        ['8','*'],
                        ['9','('],
                        ['0',')'],
                        ['-', '_'],
                        ['=','+'],
                        'delete'
                    ],
                    [

'capslock','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p',
                        ['[','{'],
                        [']','}']
                    ],
                    [

                      'shift','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',
                        [';',':'],
                        ["'",'&quot;'],
                        ['\\','|']
                    ],
                    [

                        'z','x','c','v','b','n','m',
                        [',','&lt;'],
                        ['.','&gt;'],
                        ['/','?'],
                        ['@',]
                    ],
                    ['space'],
                    ['reset']
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
$('.softkeys').click(function(event) {
    $('#d').text($("#a").val());
});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the onchange event, to prevent the text being longer than what you want

```
$("#a").change(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var max = $(this).attr('maxlength') || 10000000;
    if(text.length > max){
        text = text.substring(0, max - 1);
    }
    $(this).val(text);
});
```

Edit: In the case the maxlength attribute is not present, this example assumes 10000000 chars is the limit